# How do we place $k$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to achieve only $n$ slopes?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, euclidean-geometry

So here's my problem: we have the total of $k$ lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that all must have a common intersection point. The lines are determined by even number of points each. For instance, we may have $2$ points that determine the first line (i.e. these points all lie on this line), then $8$ points that determine the second line (i.e. these points lie on these line / are collinear) and so on. The sum of these points is $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that is even.

Now, the question is, what is the optimal way to draw these lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that the slopes determined by the lines plus the slopes determined by each couple of points i.e. $\binom{n}{2}$ in total (some of these might be the same!) is minimized to exactly $n$ slopes in total? Essentially, I am asking the way to place the $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that

Comment: $k+\binom{n}{2}=n$ will not be possible since $\binom{n}{2}>n$ if $n\geq4$. What do you mean by the sum of the $l_j$?

Comment: My bad, I meant we can at max have $\binom{n}{2}$ slopes in total determined by $n$ points if all of these are different. But they are not.